# ASP.NET/Entity Framework - как изменить модель данных при изменении структуры БД ?

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, entity-framework

**Добрый день!**

Имею такой вопрос:

Система строилась по принципу DB-first, и вот  у нас изменилась структура БД. Как изменить уже готовую модель данных, не пересоздавая ее ? Подскажите, пожалуйста. VS 2010, Framework 4.

Спасибо

Comment: Ну судя по метке EntityFramework то почему бы просто ее не проапдейтить с помощью пункта контекстного меню "Update Model from Database" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо воспользоваться опцией "Update Model from Database" как упомянули в комментарии нацелив подключение на нужную бд

Либо вручную поправив edmx файл (актуально только в случае досконального понимания всего его синтаксиса и структуры)