# Как обновить Модель Entity при изменении структуры БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Исходные данные : БД - MSSQL, Проект на C#, Подход Entity - Model First.

Вопрос в следующем - как изменить модель(И соответственно классы сущностей) в проекте, если пришлось что то менять в ручную в БД ? Например, добавить столбец или индекс к одной из таблиц при том, что в  базе есть данные. Как обновить `Entity` для такой измененной БД ?

Comment: может `update model from database`? такой вопрос уже задавался кажется - [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/273550/asp-net-entity-framework-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%91%D0%94?rq=1)

Comment: @Buka данные при этом не пострадают?

Comment: при добавлении таблицы/колонки/индекса данные не постарадют, если же у Вас структура изменится кардинально: например столбец перекочует в другую таблицу и т.д., то тогда нужно написать скрипт миграции данных